# Nginx can't create files inside 755 permissions folder

Tags: linux, nginx, file-permissions

I have a folder with 755 permissions with `foo-bar:foo-bar` chown. Nginx throws an error that it can't save a file inside it, it only can when I change the folder's recursive permissions to 777. How can I allow nginx to create the files inside this folder with 755 permissions?

My user groups:

```
foo-bar: foo-bar www-data
www-data: www-data
```

Should I just add `www-data` to `foo-bar` group? Will this work? Or is it better to do something else?

Answer (score 1):

Permission 755 can be translated to `rwxr-xr-x`, meaning the owner can read, write and open (eXecute) the folder, the group and "others" can only read and open. If nginx is running as www-data it won't be able to write to the folder unless you change the permissions to 777.

If you add www-data to foo-bar group you will still have to set the permission to 775 for the group members to be able to write to the folder.

Comment: Are there any security risks in this instance to use 775 instead of 755?